# Java: Android: Retrofit - using Call but, Response{code = 401,message=unauthorized}

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

trying to use Retrofit to access stuff, with themoviedatabase API, but i'm getting a crash, without any thrown exception or error message... I'm new to Retrofit, but i searched some documentation, and this is what i have(i'm using the Retrofit 2.0):

```
    String movieToSearch = "fight";
    String ENDPOINT = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";
    String API_KEY = "&api_key=------------------------------";
    Retrofit adapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    TMDBAPI apiService = adapter.create(TMDBAPI.class);
    String query = movieToSearch + API_KEY;

    Call<List<Movie>> call = apiService.getMovieList(query);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Movie>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Movie>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            List<Movie> movieList = (response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

What am i doing worng here? :/

[EDIT] i added a / to the end point, and changed the method in the interface to this:
`@GET("search/movie")
    Call<List<Movie>> getMovieList( @Query("query") String query);`

the problem now is, the response has body = null, in the rawResponse, it has a message saying =
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=fight%26api_key%-----

do i have to set up a client?

Comment: But what is the error, some exception? please add more info, are you setting up the right permissions? internet permission?

Comment: yes i have the internet permission

Comment: Well I think you need to test before your request, I usually use Postman for that task, one  I have clear the request then can go to retrofit.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: ok thats cool, i've tried and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can see your problem, the search should be do like this:

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=###&query=iron sky
```

So, the problem is how are you forming the URL.

Comment: so after reading i changed the string API_KEY=----- just for the value, and passed both, query and API_KEY as arguments, and used the dynamic headers: Call<List<Movie>> searchMovieList( @Query("query") String query, @Header("api_key") String key); but still not working

Comment: i used the postman app, and it worked with the apikey, after the query, but in the method, i should use Query or header, or just 1 query with all?

Comment: Call<List<Movie>> getMovieList( @Query("query") String query, @Query("api_key") String api_key);

Comment: with that change, it doesn't reach the call.enqueue(...) method. Doesn't give error, nor an exception..

Comment: Call<List<Movie>> call = apiService.getMovieList(query, api_key);

Comment: yes i did that, still nuthing, im searching on google about, error 401, unauthorized, and im not the first, and it's something about okhttp..

Answer (score -2):

I Figured what i was doing wrong, the result off the request i am making, gives more objects in the json... Just create an object with said fields, and with a List.