# Webservice not working in Android Retrofit , but works in Postman and Swift / iOS, Getting 401 Unauthorized

Tags: android, ios, retrofit, postman, okhttp

**BRIEFING BEFORE 'technical stuff'**
Not new to working with Retrofit but came across this strange behaviour which I am having very hard time to understand and fix,
I have two web service, both work fine as expected in Postman and iOS but only one works in Retrofit and not the other,
In my defence I can say I am getting (Unauthorized) response,which means I was able to hit the server and get a result
In API developer's defence he says it works in Postman and other devices so not a service issue

If any Retrofit expert out there tell me what retrofit may be doing behind my back in order to get this error?

**TECHNICAL STUFF**
Talking about the type of service , It contains ***Authorization Bearer token*** as header which expires every 6 hours and contains no params at all (so it should be easy, right ?) and a simple url
http://hashchuna.nn-assets.com/api/locations
Unfortunately the header token cant be shared with valid key, cos it'l be expired before anyone can try it, but here it's anyway **Authorization Bearer 3d44626a55dbb024725984e0d37868336fd7e48a**

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**
I am using okhttp intercept to add Authorization Header to request using both **addHeader/header** method, no spaces in the url cos there r no params
[Getting 401 unauthorized error in retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33432545/getting-401-unauthorized-error-in-retrofit)
[Java: Android: Retrofit - using Call but, Response{code = 401,message=unauthorized}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248365/java-android-retrofit-using-call-but-responsecode-401-message-unauthoriz)
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1290
But non of them helped

**WARNING**
Now the tricky part to keep in mind, the token when expired must give 401 error which is expected, but the problem is even for freshly created token I get 401 , which is my core problem

**LOG**

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://hashchuna.nn-assets.com/api/locations http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Authorization: Bearer 7c0d53de006b6de931f7d8747b22442354cecef9
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- 401 Unauthorized http://hashchuna.nn-assets.com/api/locations (773ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 10:44:11 GMT
D/OkHttp: Server: Apache
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.15
D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
D/OkHttp: Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=u477o8g0q387t92hms4nhc14n1; path=/
D/OkHttp: Vary: Authorization
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PleskLin
D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5
D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
```

**CODE**
Intercept

```
Request request = chain
                        .request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        //.header("Authorization","Bearer "+ SharedPrefsUtils.getSPinstance().getAccessToken(context))
                        .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer 1ed6b7c1839e02bbf7a1b4a8dbca84d23127c68e")
                        //.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                        //.cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                        .build();
```

Retrofit Instance

```
private Api getApiInstance(Context context) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logInter = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logInter.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient mIntercepter = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new RequestResponseInterseptor(context))
                .addInterceptor(logInter)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofitInstance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                //.addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(mIntercepter)
                .build();
        return retrofitInstance.create(Api.class);
    }
```

Comment: Are you ABSOLUTELY sure you're appending an updated token to your headers? Sounds like you're just using an old token.

Comment: @C0D3LIC1OU5 Yes, I know the problem sounds like thats the OBVIOUS mistake, but its not, I even hardcoded as soon as i generated new token, unless some caching by retrofit is taking place which I am not aware of

Comment: Another thing to double check is that the KEYs you add to the header match what server expects and don't have typos in them. Like the "Authorization Bearer" key for the token value (or whatever you're calling them)

Comment: An OKHttp intercept is the right way to go in my experience.

Are you using the right key for the header? Could be "Authorization" "Bearer" or "Authorization Bearer". Based on some testing in postman, I think it is the third.

Comment: what is this used for? `D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=u477o8g0q387t92hms4nhc14n1; path=/`

Comment: @BrianCooley, thats somthing new, I was using Authorization as key and "Bearer token" as value, let me try Authorization Bearer as key

Comment: @C0D3LIC1OU5 not sure, as I am not entirely good at decoding the response header

Comment: @BrianCooley just reference your iOS app and copy keys/values from there. It'll save you time

Comment: @BrianCooley same error for all key value, the entire header is getting ignored

Comment: Could you give me an unexpired token so that I can test?

Comment: @BNK `961e171e4d27c95f29a31c91cbef2d6863c760fe` u can try this, created just now

Comment: I have just tried it with Postman, still 401 response code

Comment: @BNK `Authorization: Bearer 961e171e4d27c95f29a31c91cbef2d6863c760fe` Can you recheck with this header, ,..

Comment: In Postman, only `Authorization` accepted, of couse the value I set is `Bearer 961e171e4d27c95f29a31c91cbef2d6863c760fe`, however, even with Postman still gets 401. Can you provide with the specs or requirement doc for that web service?

Comment: @BNK I know postman adds two additional headers while making request `.addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "154b46f9-593e-a538-e7b3-124d60e6a48b")` can this be blocking other user from using the same token, not sure

Comment: I have just tried with HttpRequester add-on in Firefox, still 401

Comment: @BNK I think I got a fare Idea, the webclient that create the Token , should call the URL as well, I will try creating from my code and update on this, or Il provide a new token

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**SOLUTION (its the COOKIE)**
Thanks to some of the tips, the actual reason for Incompatibility of service is , Supposedly POSTMAN and iOS client store and reuse `COOKIE` all by itself when requests are made without any need for explicit handling, Cookie in Postman can be tested using [Postman Intercepter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en) ,but cant be edited because chrome does not allow editing cookie by plugins

However Retrofit/OkHttp unless specified will consider it disabled(for security reason maybe) ,
Cookie is added either inside `Interseptor` as one of the header `addHeader("Cookie","KEY-VALUE")`
 or
Use `cookieJar` to add into

```
OkHttpClient mIntercepter = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(mCookieJar)
                .addInterceptor(new RequestResponseInterseptor(context))
                .addInterceptor(logInter)
                .build();
```

based on your need and cookie type

Comment: For your `but cant be edited because chrome does not allow editing cookie by plugins`,  I think you can try Postman App for Win/MacOS at https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Yes I shud give that a try, could have saved me lot of time if I thot of it before,..

Comment: What is **mCookieJar**??

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it's a library, let's yu add cookies to ur request by creating an object and adding values

Comment: Still not able to get the response. There is some session issue showing in server.But since it runs in web and iOS as well as i have no other option just to check my code.

Comment: What is mCookieJar?

Comment: @kgandroid CookieJar is a library to manage cookie, mCookieJar is just instance/object of that library

Answer (score 7):

I think you are overriding other headers `Retrofit` is adding for you, causing your API to not care about your `Authorization` header. Code below will add a header to your existing headers instead of overriding them.

```
    OkHttpClient mIntercepter = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            ...
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                 @Override 
                 public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + "1ed6b7c1839e02bbf7a1b4a8dbca84d23127c68e").build();
                        return chain.proceed(request);
            })
            ...
            .build();
```

Format of those headers *is* correct here, key should be `Authorization` and value should be `Bearer 1ed6b7c1839e02bbf7a1b4a8dbca84d23127c68e` (in your case).

Comment: I am using Retrofit 2.1.0 , both `RestAdapter` and `RequestInterceptor` has been replaced with `Request` and  `OkHttpClient `

Comment: But this looks same as my intercept right,,? my `RequestResponseInterseptor` extends `Interceptor` and creates the same request, ,,you can check my Intercept code

Comment: Not sure, I don't see full code for your `RequestResponseInterseptor` class. Key here is overriding the `intercept` function, which I don't see you doing anywhere.

Comment: Ok, ya actually since der was too much of code I pasted only small part,,, yes the `RequestResponseInterseptor` extends `interceptor`, `intercept` contains code same as yours nothing else

Comment: Ok. BTW, the line you are using is not correct - you have the correct headers commented out (it's the line above). Have you tried hardcoding your token with the correct header keys?  `.header("Authorization","Bearer "+ "1ed6b7c1839e02bbf7a1b4a8dbca84d23127c68e")`.

Comment: I was trying `Authorization Bearer` as key as BrianCooley mentioned in his comment, but that also returns same result as passing this key,, I'm pretty sure the issue is around header, but as u see in log, request is perfect

Answer (score 3):

In my case, unfortunately, none of advices listed in @Ujju 's solution worked (i.e. neither "Cookie" header nor `CookieJar` applied). The only thing that helped me is just replacing `addInterceptor` with `addNetworkInterceptor`, and everything began to work.

Comment: This actually solved my problem as well! Strangely enough this *only* happens for synchronous calls - `call.execute()` (not for `call.enqueue()`) and (in my case) *only* for actual production calls to the server and not to calls to a local dev server in my WiFi network.

I found the reason: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

The NetworkInterceptor also follows redirects and is applied **twice**. Once for the initial request and the second time for the 302.

Answer (score 2):

```
401 Unauthorized http://www.stackoverflow.com/api/login?email=test@test.com&password=123456
Date: Fri, 07 Apr 2017 11:23:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) PHP/5.6.29
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.29
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
Content-Length: 41
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
{"msg":"Invalid Credentials"}
```

I was facing issue like that not able fetch error message.

When server throwing error like  `401` or other error we are getting `null body` from server.But you can get error message from server in `errorBody`

```
String response = response.errorBody().string()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my problem was not about not getting error msg, I got the errorBody just fine, In my case the msg was somthing like `{
  "errors": [  {  "code": "bad_request",  "title": "not_authorised"   }  ]}`

Comment: for me it was filesize issue please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55913121/3904109

Answer (score 1):

I faced with this problem as well.
Requests work fine not only in POSTMAN, but also in CURl.
Having spent a lot of time I found a solution.

Service example for login:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("authentication/login")
fun login(
    @Field("login") login: String,
    @Field("password") password: String
): Single<Void>
```

Provide okhttp client:

```
private fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {

   val cookieManager = CookieManager()
   cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL)

   val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .cookieJar(JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
      .addNetworkInterceptor(provideRequestInterceptor())
      .addNetworkInterceptor(provideLoggingInterceptor())
      .protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
      .build()

   return client
}
```

Make enable JavaNetCookieJar:

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$okHttpVersion"
```

Provide authorization:

```
private fun provideRequestInterceptor() = Interceptor {
    val builder = it.request().newBuilder().url(it.request().url())

    val tokenStr = BuildConfig.SONAR_TOKEN
    builder.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+ getBase64String(tokenStr+":"))

    it.proceed(builder.build())
}

private fun getBase64String(value: String): String {
    return Base64.encodeToString(value.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")), Base64.NO_WRAP)
}
```