# E/Error: retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

This is the response i am trying to fetch from the api

```
{
    "success": {
        "id": 35,
        "otp": 9830,
        "msg": "Otp has sent on this number"
    }
}
```

The response is working absolutely fine when checked in postman . However when i try to fetch the same json by parsing the response in Hashmap format in android kotlin i get the  E/Error: retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized

Now This is My android rxjava kotlin code as below where i am passing all necessery parameters but the response goes to error block. The code is as follows

```
override fun login(api_token: String, name: String, mobile: String, lat: String, lon: String, address: String) {

      var subscribe = api.login(api_token,mobile.toInt(),lat.toDouble(),lon.toDouble(),address).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ list: LoginParentResponseModel? ->
                    Log.i("login",list!!.toString())
                    view.showProgress(false)
                    view.loadLoginSuccess(list!!.success)
                }, { error ->
                    view.loadLoginFailure("loginfailed")
                    view.showProgress(false)
                    view.showErrorMessage("problen"+error.toString())


                })
        subscriptions.add(subscribe)


}
```

Now this is the Model class for reponse handling

```
data class LoginParentResponseModel(val success : Map<String,String>,val error : Map<String,String>)
```

Now this is the api and its parameters which is fine as like i am using in postman

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/register?")
    fun login(@Field("api_token") id: String, @Field("mobile") mobile: Int,@Field("lat") lat: Double,@Field("lon") lon: Double,@Field("address") address: String): Observable<LoginParentResponseModel>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: 401 is the return code from the server.  Its saying you aren't authorized, or that authentication failed.  You need to debug on the server what it got and why it sent back a 401.

Comment: Maybe this question could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42375566/getting-401-unauthorised-in-retrofit-but-works-in-postman-and-swift

Comment: but how can i even check error body

Comment: any idea please

Comment: You should change response type to `Response<Observable<LoginParentResponseModel>>` then you can see error body

Comment: Add request logging in your retrofit(https://stackoverflow.com/a/33328524/1320616). That way you will be able to view request(request body, url, headers etc.) as well as the response. Once you  are able to view the request parameters, use any rest client like Postman and try to hit the server with the same parameters.